# Calculating the address for a soon-to-be-deployed contract

Tags: contract-deployment

How is it possible to calculate the address for a soon-to-be-deployed contract?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

A contract will not have an address until the transaction deploying it to the blockchain is confirmed within a block.

Comment: Correct, but the address can be computed in advance using the sender's address + current nonce :-)

Comment: hoh hoh you devil you